# Show that by induction method that $2^{2^n}+1$ has $7$ in unit's place for all $n\geq 2$.

Tags: induction

Show that by induction method that   $2^{2^n}+1$ has $7$ in unit's place  for all $n\geq 2$.

I have tried to show this with the  following way :

Let $f(n)=2^{2^n}+1$.
Then for $n=2,f(2)=2^{2^2}+1=17\Rightarrow  f(2)\equiv 7(\mod 10) $
Suppose for $n=m$, the result is true i.e., $f(m)=2^{2^m}+1=10p+7$, where $p$ is an integer.
 How can I show this result for $n=m+1$ ?

Comment: $f(1)=5$; you want $f(2)$ in that base case calculation.

Comment: You’re making much too big a deal of this, I believe. Did you actually evaluate $2^{2^2}$ and $2^{2^3}$?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. A correction has been done.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $$f(m+1)=2^{2^{m+1}}+1=2^{2^m\cdot2}+1=\left(2^{2^m}\right)^2+1=\big(f(m)-1\big)^2+1$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: When you square a number ending in $6$, don’t you get another such number?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Note that $2^{2^{n+1}}=\left(2^{2^n}\right)^2$ and $(10k+6)^2=100k^2+120 k+36$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: apply induction to $2^{2^m}$

Additional possibility: investigate the units digits of small powers of $2$ and formulate and prove a stronger (but simpler) hypothesis by induction of which the given statement is a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Let the statement F(n) be true and with F(n+1) the power of 2 that is 2^m becomes 2^(n+1) which is a number of the form 4k. And 2^4k will always yield a 6 in its last digit and by adding 1 you will get 7 in the last digit.